# How to get all the operations done on an oracle table be imported into hive for processing?(not just actual data in table, but the operations also)

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a table in oracle db which gets multiple transactions done (lets say around 100 million inserts,updates or deletes in a day). I want to get all the transactions happening in that table to be brought into hive for processing through spark or hive.

For example:
lets say a record in that oracle table goes through initial insert operation followed by 5 updates to same/different columns and finally gets deleted. I want to capture all such operations for all the records in that table and import into hive.
We want to find records with number of operations that exceed a threshold for specific columns and pull a report on them.

Has anyone come across such a use case? Appreciate any help in achieving this.

Comment: You ned to tell a little more about the ORACLE stuff first.

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly you are looking for? The DB version is oracle 12c R2.

Comment: Cdc asc key time stamp